# ERROR: could not read block 84 in file "base/16386/670007": Input/output error

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have a database, when I look for some tables in the database it shows error

`ERROR:  could not read block 84 in file "base/16386/670007": Input/output error`

I am using postgresql.

Whenever this error is encountered I have to reload the table again and again. But this is not a permanent solution. How I can resolve this error? I have tried to take backup using pg_dump but its also not working.

Comment: Have you tried moving the DB to other hardware or just change the disk(s)?

Answer (score 3):

Your storage subsystem is failing. This is not a PostgreSQL error, as such, it's an error from the underlying file system or disks.

You might learn more from the output of the `dmesg` command and/or the kernel logs.